# Empty KSQL Stream

Tags: ksqldb

I'm having a problem with fetching data from Kafka topic.
this topic content object, I didn't really know how to store some variable in the stream.
and I'm sure that the topic exists

i have:

```
Ticket object:{

header object{storeID,storename.....}

body object{...}

}
```

i wanna put storeID in the stream

```
create stream test (StoreID VARCHAR) with (KAFKA_TOPIC= 'output__tfrema',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

i try that example but it give me 0 data , i expect it to give me at least 10000 data.

thx any way

Answer (score 0):

If there's no results returned it can be for several reasons.

- Make sure you've `SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';` so you read all messages from the beginning of the topic
- Are there deserialisation errors in your KSQL server log?

You can read more here: https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1

Comment: Everything is good, but the stream is empty.          I don't know maybe I can't write StoreID just like this!!!

Comment: Hmmm looking again, if it's Avro, you don't need to declare the columns. Just `create stream test with (KAFKA_TOPIC= 'output__tfrema',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');` will work, if you have a valid schema.

Comment: i try that one but it says : VALUE_FORMAT should be set in WITH clause of CREATE STREAM/TABLE statement.

Comment: i found the solution here : https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/nested-json-data
thx
did you write somethings about the aggregate in the KSQL !!